# How to distinguish in vs a in andare when you express the means of going?

Tags: prepositions

I encountered the following two sentences in my Italian Rosetta Stone program:

> Vanno a cavallo sulla spiaggia.
>
> Va in bicicletta sulla spiaggia.

However, I can't understand why the former uses `a` while the latter uses `in` in preposition. Both use `andare` and express what to ride in to *andare* in *spiaggia*.

Is there any explicit criterion on when to use `in` vs `a` in *andare*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with all prepositions, there won't always be hard and fast rules for why you use one over the other. Both in and a can be used to refer to a ***means*** of doing something. Your example, *andare a cavallo vs andare in bicicletta*, reveals the following general rules:

You often use ***in*** with means of transportation dealing with *vehicles*:

> e.g. andare in macchina, in treno, in aereo, in pullman

However, there are also cases where you employ ***a*** for means of transportation that is *animate*:

> e.g. andare a piedi, andare a cavallo

Comment: Thanks. Then do I have to memorize all the pairs of the nouns and its prepositions? Or are there also cases where you use `a` for words like `macchina`, `treno`, or `aereo` and `in` for `piedi`, `barca a vela`, or `cavallo`?

Comment: @Gardecolo Beware! You say *andare **in** barca a vela*. I suppose gbutters's example only referred to the *a* in *barca a vela*.

Comment: Apparently, you say *in* with vehicles (*in macchina*, *in barca*, *in treno*) and *a* with “animal” transportation (*a piedi*, *a cavallo*, *a dorso d'asino*).

Comment: @DaG Ah, that's plausible. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I edited the response to reflect your comments. Thanks @DaG.